# Extra Carriage Return inserted during multiline textbox postback in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, textbox

Environment : Visual studio 2013 - Framework 4.0, IE11, Oracle 11g

I have an ASP.NET TextBox with TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine that is getting filled with data from Oracle. The same data is getting added to a ViewState variable as well, as I need to find a difference between the original database value and multi-line textbox value when a page is posted back upon Save button click.

If I am changing the value in the textbox, it should be different. However, the values are equated to be different even if I am not changing anything in the multi-line textbox while saving it.

The strange part is, this only occurs in IE11. Google chrome is fine!

I've tried converting both values to ASCII upon save button click and found that multi-line textbox has extra carriage return (ASCII value - 13) for new line.

The string in ViewState converts the new line to ASCII 10, whereas same string in Textbox converts the new line to ASCII 13(Carriage return) and ASCII 10(new line feed).

My solutions to this is to remove the extra 13(carriage return) from textbox while comparing it and saving it.

I just wanted to see if anyone else has ever encountered this problem, is there a .NET fix to it or I am doing something wrong? (which I doubt as its working fine in chrome)

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Having the same issue. Customers have been complaining about it since they got pushed IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general rule of thumb for web design that is still useful: IE will drive you crazy.